# Laravel limit doesn't work with more than 5k records

Tags: laravel

Not sure what is happening.

I am trying to limit the controller response to 3000 data.
Currently, my database has more than 5k data on it, when I try to do `limit(3000)`, the result is only 2k plus records.

code:

```
$notes = Notes::where('status', 'done')->limit(3000)->get();  
return count($notes)    

result is 2181
```

*current records with status done, almost 4k

using Laravel 5.8

Comment: Which part you don't understand? You get 2181 records with status done. That is less than your limit so everything works correctly.

Comment: Funny is I got almost 4k records with status done

Comment: post your Notes model here too.

Comment: I think there is not enough record

Comment: Are you soft deleting items? Maybe they are still showing up in the database but the query will leave them out of the results

Comment: Not sure about soft deleting but Im not deleting anything.